# "Trying to get property of non-object" error with PHP 7 (worked in PHP 5.4)

Tags: php

This is my function:

```
function get_cat_option($data, $pid, $cid=0, $parent=0){

    static $i = 1;
    $tab = str_repeat(" ",$i);
    static $a = 0;
    $pusher = "-";
    $showPusher = str_repeat($pusher,$a);
    if(isset($data[$parent]) && $data[$parent])
    {
        $html = "$tab";
        $i++;
        foreach($data[$parent] as $v)
        {

            $a++;           
            $child = get_cat_option($data, $pid, $cid, $v->category_id);
            if($v->category_parent_id == 0)
            {
                $listChild = "";
            }
            if($v->category_id == $pid)
            {
                $selected = ' selected';
            }
            else
            {
                $selected = '';
            }
            if($v->category_id == $cid)
            {
                $disabled = ' disabled';
            }
            else
            {
                $disabled = '';
            }
            $html .= "$tab";
            $html .= '<option value="'.$v->category_id.'"'.$selected.$disabled.'>'.$showPusher.' '.$v->category_title.'</option>';
            $a--;
            if($child)
            {
                $i--;
                $html .= $child;
                $html .= "$tab";
            }
        }
        $html .= "$tab";
        return $html;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and I call it by:

```
<dt><select name="category" size="1" class="field form" style="width: 325px">
        <option value="">--</option>
        <?=get_cat_option($parent_data,$data['product_category'])?>
</select></dt>
```

Error is:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in
```

Error line is:

```
$child = get_cat_option($data, $pid, $cid, $v->category_id);
```

This code worked perfectly in PHP 5.4 but now I'm using PHP 7.

How can I fix it?

Comment: _**Please don't add garbage text to get around Stack Overflow's content filters.** They're there for a reason._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely referring to the `$v->category_id` argument. If `category_id` doesn't exist in `$v`, then it throws an error.

Verify that your `$data[$parent]` object is correct before looping through it:

```
var_dump($data[$parent]);
```

Comment: fixed... in  foreach($data[$parent] as $v) change $data[$parent] to $data. i don't know what to say...:)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely that there is no property "category_id" in $v, so it is throwing a warning. You could check for its existance, using

```
if (isset($v->category_id)) {
// do something
}
```

or us the ?? operator to set a default.

```
$category_id = $v->category_id ?? $fallback;
```